# Why there are live and neutral wires attached to house's wall sockets

Tags: voltage, ac

If AC voltage is alternative,  why there are two (Suppose there is no earth wire)  wires attached to the wall socket:  live or hot, neutral wires? And I think that in small home generators there is no need to specify which wire is the live wire?

I've read that the neutral wire is connected to the ground. Where it's connected, I mean at the house or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *must* be two wires for a complete circuit.

Now, in a *[balanced](http://www.equitech.com/articles/bpng.html)* AC circuit, both wires provide an alternating voltage with respect to ground (earth).  When one wire is positive, the other is negative.

However, in an unbalanced system, one wire is *[neutral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_and_neutral)*, which should ideally be at 0V with respect to ground, and the other is *hot* which *alternates* positive and negative with respect to ground.

In either case, *both* wires have (ideally) equal and opposite current.

If I'm not mistaken, in the USA, the neutral and ground are connected together at the meter base (service entrance).

For a generator that isn't referenced to ground, the AC voltage is simply *across* the 'hot' and 'neutral'.

[There are devices](http://www.furmansound.com/product.php?id=IT-20_II) for converting unbalanced AC to balanced AC power.

Comment: That first article seems to ignore the safety implications of having a balanced AC circuit.

Comment: Thank you, @Alfred .. Please correct me if i'm wrong --in unbalanced AC circuits,the neutral is connected to the ground(Earth, in this case),and if the 'hot' wire is denoted as L and the neutral as N, the following is happening: 

For the first positive half of L's voltage cycle, the electrons are moving from L to an appliance then to N which is connected to earth(at some point).

At the second -Negative half- of L's voltage, it's now negative with respect to the ground(earth,which is 0V), the electrons now are moving from N (earth, because N is connected to it) to the appliance then to L?

Comment: And does the earth in this kind of systems considered as the second wire that completes the circuits?

Comment: @MustafaAliraqi, that's not quite correct.  The earthing of the neutral wire simply sets the *voltage* on the neutral to 0V with respect to earth.  However, there is no (or should be no) current into or out of the ground (earth).  That is to say, the circuit is still complete even if the neutral is disconnected from ground.

Comment: This is exactly what confusing me, @Alfred .. How does electrical current flow from the Neutral wire to the Line wire through the device in the second half and yet it doesn't shock us when we touch it and we don't call it a hot wire.

Comment: @MustafaAliraqi, the fact that there is a current through the neutral wire doesn't imply that it will shock you.  For that, you need a *voltage* on the neutral wire.  If the you have one hand on the ground rod and one hand on the neutral wire (don't do this! - this is just a *thought* experiment), there will be no current through you *since there is no voltage difference between your hands*.  This holds even if there is current through the neutral wire and no current through the ground wire.  As long as the two wires have zero voltage *difference*, you will not be shocked while touching both.

Comment: So if I connected a negative volatge to one of the device's electrical terminal and the neutral from the wall outlet which is at zero voltage, would  a current pass through the device? And from where that current on the neutral wire came from? Thanks @Alfred for bearing with me but its really confusing.

Comment: @MustafaAliraqi, it's not clear to me what you're asking.  Perhaps you could draw the schematic of what you propose?  Do keep in mind that there must be a *circuit* for there to be current, i.e., charge flows along a closed path.  In your comment above, it isn't clear to me how you envision "connect[ing] a negative voltage".  A voltage source has *two* terminals.  Where is the other terminal connected?

Comment: I'll post another question later and try to explain it in better words with a schematic.  I know that a circuit should be closed and all the other basics of electricity. And the links you provided were a great help too.